# Why the following graphql schema does not compile with HotChocolate?

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm trying to put together a more complex stuff than Getting started guide with HotChocolate and I hit a wall, and the documentation does not help.

I have multiple questions:

- What I'm doing wrong here? I went through all the examples they have and it seems I'm doing the right thing, but the error shows something totally opposite.
- How can I access to that `Errors` property? I haven't found any further detail in their BananaCake graphql UI

`QueryType` class:

```
public class QueryType : ObjectType
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        descriptor
            .Name(OperationTypeNames.Query)
            .Description("Represents the Document entity of the system");

        descriptor
            .Field("document")
            .Description("query field description")
            .Type<ListType<DocumentDtoType>>()
            .Resolve(r =>
            {
                return new List<DocumentDto>
                {
                    new DocumentDto { Id = 1, Name = "one", Description = "one d" },
                    new DocumentDto { Id = 2, Name = "two", Description = "two d" },
                };
                // return new List<string>
                // {
                //     "whatever",
                //     "anything"
                // };
            });
    }
}
```

The type:

```
public class DocumentDto
{
    public DocumentDto()
    {
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Uri? Uri { get; set; }
}
```

The DocumentDtoType:

```
public class DocumentDtoType : ObjectType<DocumentDto>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<DocumentDto> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor
            .Name("Unique identifier of the entity")
            .Field(f => f.Id)
            .Type<IdType>();

        descriptor
            .Name("Name of the document")
            .Field(f => f.Name)
            .Type<StringType>();

        descriptor
            .Name("Description of the document entity")
            .Field(f => f.Description)
            .Type<StringType>();

        descriptor
            .Field(f => f.Uri).Ignore();
    }
}
```

Setup:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType<QueryType>()
    .AddType<DocumentDtoType>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.MapGraphQL();

app.Run();
```

The error:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5102
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EncyclopediaGalactica/Services/Document/Document.Graphql
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      HotChocolate.SchemaException: For more details look at the `Errors` property.
      
      1. The specified name is not a valid GraphQL name. (Parameter 'value') (Document.Graphql.Types.DocumentDtoType)
      
         at HotChocolate.Configuration.TypeInitializer.DiscoverTypes()
         at HotChocolate.Configuration.TypeInitializer.Initialize()
         at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.Setup.InitializeTypes(SchemaBuilder builder, IDescriptorContext context, IReadOnlyList`1 types)
         at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.Setup.Create(SchemaBuilder builder, LazySchema lazySchema, IDescriptorContext context)
         at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.Create(IDescriptorContext context)
         at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.HotChocolate.ISchemaBuilder.Create(IDescriptorContext context)
         at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.CreateSchemaAsync(ConfigurationContext context, RequestExecutorSetup setup, RequestExecutorOptions executorOptions, IServiceProvider schemaServices, TypeModuleChangeMonitor typeModuleChangeMonitor, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.CreateSchemaServicesAsync(ConfigurationContext context, RequestExecutorSetup setup, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.GetRequestExecutorNoLockAsync(String schemaName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.GetRequestExecutorAsync(String schemaName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorProxy.GetRequestExecutorAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at HotChocolate.AspNetCore.HttpPostMiddlewareBase.HandleRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
         at HotChocolate.AspNetCore.HttpPostMiddlewareBase.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<UseCancellation>b__1>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      HotChocolate.SchemaException: For more details look at the `Errors` property.
```

Answer (score 0):

- Method `IObjectTypeDescriptor.Name` defines a name of GraphQL type that will be exposed to the output schema. And the way you used it is incorrect:

  1. Type name can not include any white space characters, as in your case `descriptor.Name("Unique identifier of the entity")`
  2. Each method call overwrites the type name so it makes no sense to call it three times
- Actually `SchemaException` prints to the console all its exceptions from the `Errors` property. In your case, the property contains only one exception: "The specified name is not a valid GraphQL name".